# send mails with different addresses according to the user request

Tags: php, email

i got four buttons for four branches.When user click the wanted button and it send a mail to that branch how to achieve this 
my code is like this

### HTML

```
<ul class="list-inline banner-social-buttons">
            <li>

                <a name="city" id="Info1" value="london" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-city"><i></i> <span class="network-name">london</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a name="city" id="Info2" value="dellhi" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-city"><i class="fa fa-taxi fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Dillhi</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a name="city" id="Info3" value="mumbai" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-city btn-none"><i class="fa fa-taxi fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Mumbai</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a name="city" id="Info4" value="madras" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-city btn-none"><i ></i> <span class="network-name">Madras</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a name="city" id="Info5" value="colombo" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-city btn-none"><i ></i> <span class="network-name">colombo</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

here i need to generate a mail and i wrote this function in my php

### php

```
$city = $_POST['city'];
$email_to = "info@outlook.com"; //The email sending to
$email_subject = "REQUEST:Dellhi"; //The subject of email

if($city == 'Madras')
{
    $email_to = "info@outlook.com";//The email sending to
    $email_subject = "REQUEST:Madras"; //The subject of email
}
```

but still it doesn't change is this correct how i do it or please guide me on any proper way to get this done!

Comment: You might want to add some punctuation to your sentences. It really helps... It might even increase the chance someone is willing to read through your post.

Comment: thanks! extremely sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify if you're getting the data by doing a `var_dump($_POST);` just as you POST the data.

Update your conditional statement as follows

```
$city = strtolower($city);
if($city == 'madras')
```

This will ensure a case insensetive match.

Comment: That way he will have to use strtolower in every if statement why not just directly use lower case $city in his html

Comment: True, but i prefer this method since even if you change HTML code to all capital this will work as long as the spelling is intact. But you have a valid point if you consider the amount of code to write in PHP :)

Comment: Edit your answer to $city = strtolower($city); and in if statement make it $city only :)

Comment: Oh yes, we could always do that and avoid more coding ;) Updated answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with your code is not very clear. I think I understand what you are trying to achieve if I am correct.

You have 4 buttons with different values:

button 1 | button 2 | button 3 | button 3

All buttons have different values which you'd want to pick up from your URL then send an email. What do you use to make a post? I see nothing making any posts to any URL. Your format might simply be using a `$_GET` unless you'd be assuming to use

```
<li>
   <button name='city' id="Info1" value="london" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-city"><i></i> <span class="network-name">london</span></button>
</li>
```

You could still use a `radio` button to show all the options then have a `submit` button to make the post for you. If you want you could even use ann all `input type="submit"` or `input type="button"` but with different `name=""` values.

Nonetheless, if I am to go with what I see, I would suggest you use a `$_GET` to deal with what I am currently seeing.

I won't now post code solutions until I am sure what you want done and how you want it done and properly done too.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML doesn't look like a form. 
Then you compare `value="madras"` (from the "form") to `Madras` in the PHP code. `==` is case sensitive.

Tips: use `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's happen.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$city=='Madras'` to `$city=='madras'`